# Form submission troubleshooting/database management in Django?

Tags: python, django, forms

So in my model. I have blank=True so that a form entered can be blank. but then when a user submits the form it writes a blank item into the database and that is not not really what I was hoping it would do. Is there some other option to control how blank forms are handled?

EDIT: In the end I would like for the form to add all the fields with characters in them to the database and omit all of the fields that don't have characters entered in to them.

models.py

```
class Cashtexts(models.Model):
    cashcode = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True) #change me to a website filter
    superPoints_Link = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)#chance to "superPoints _Username"
    varolo_username = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    swagbucks_username = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    neobux_username = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    topline_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    Paidviewpoint_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    cashcrate_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
```

And here's the view

```
def submit_win(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if Cashtexts.objects.filter(cashcode=request.POST['cashcode']).exists() or Cashtexts.objects.filter(superPoints_Link=request.POST['superPoints_Link']).exists() or Cashtexts.objects.filter(varolo_username= request.POST['varolo_username']).exists() or Cashtexts.objects.filter( swagbucks_username = request.POST['swagbucks_username']).exists() or Cashtexts.objects.filter(neobux_username = request.POST['neobux_username']).exists() or Cashtexts.objects.filter(superPoints_Link=request.POST['topline_id']).exists() or Cashtexts.objects.filter(superPoints_Link=request.POST['Paidviewpoint_id']).exists() or Cashtexts.objects.filter(superPoints_Link=request.POST['cashcrate_id']).exists() == False:
            form = CashtextsForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                c={}
                c.update(csrf(request))
                form.save()
                return render_to_response('submitted_page.html',c)
        else: #Error message reading wither you didnt insert codes or you enter the same code twice
            error = 'you have already entered that code'
            ref_create = CashtextsForm()
            return render_to_response('submit.html', {'ref_create': ref_create,'error':error})
    else: #displays the page when the user asks to go to the submit page
        ref_create = CashtextsForm()
        return render_to_response('submit.html', {'ref_create': ref_create}, RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: I would like for the form to enter all the field that contain characters and for the form to omit entering empty strings I realising i could just do this with multiple submit button but that becomes a pain for more than  2 or 3 fields.

Comment: Thanks for adding your code. It looks like I misunderstood your question, so I've deleted my answer because it's not really relevant. I hope you find a solution. As a general tip, think about changing your model to just two fields: one that describes the type of code (cash code, super points etc) and the other that stores the value. You might find it simplifies your code.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like for the form to enter all the field that contain
>   characters and for the form to omit entering empty strings I realising
>   i could just do this with multiple submit button but that becomes a
>   pain for more than 2 or 3 fields.

Well if you don't want empty strings, then I can only assume you want None for fields left empty.
In the first place you need the Model (and thus the database) to allow that, otherwise it won't work.

I believe the following should work: (although I'm not sure why you'd really want this)

```
class Cashtexts(models.Model):
    cashcode = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
```